# Simplest to break a byte down to 8 bits?

Tags: java

I have a `byte` and want to get a collection of 8 bits (represented as 0 or 1 in any built-in integer type - `boolean`, `int`, `char`). Is there any built-in way to do this?

Comment: A sample input and output would be very helpful in understanding the question more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function?

```
public static int getBit(byte b, int bit)
{
    int power = 1 << bit;
    return (b & power) ? 1 : 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(getBit(0x55, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: The mechanical bit manipulation approach is obvious; I was wondering about more high-level ways.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) and its methods [BitSet.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D%29) and [BitSet.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get%28int%29) .

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, but somehow I can't use it. Eclipse tells me `BitSet` only has a constructor and no more methods. My `BitSet` is broken!

Comment: You can try copying the following snippet and see if it works for you.  : http://ideone.com/AVATO3 BitSet was introduced in JDK 1.0, so it shouldn't be related to Java version.

Comment: Found the problem. I'm programming for Android, and `BitSet` only became available with the most recent Android platform release.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way would be to convert the byte to an integer, and then use the built in functions to convert to binary. Since the byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer, you can actually use it like this:

```
byte b = (byte)53;
String binary = Integer.toString((int)b, 2); // convert to base 2
```

Comment: D'oh, bringing string parser into bit operations?

Comment: Hm. Seems inefficient to convert to `String` and back. But thanks.

Comment: Since an int in java has a max value of 2,147,483,647 (10 digits). it is often best to represent a binary number as a string. Otherwise, converting 1024 (10000000000) would overflow as it is 11 digits. EDIT: remembered that bytes are only 8-bits (as I wrote above, doh) which means that the problem with overflow would never happen.